# Log Analytics Workspace - Regenerate Workspace keys

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-log-analytics

I have a question that I can't find the answer to in MS Documentation in regards to the Log Analytics Workspace keys. Does anybody know if I go to the Agent Management for a Log Analytics Workspace and hit Regenerate for a key, does it affect the connection for existing agents that were onboarded using the old key (will machines that were onboarded previously be disconnected)? Or it will only affect future onboarding machines (meaning I cannot onboard using the old key)?

When I try to click on Regenerate, I get this message which is confusing a bit:
"This will nullify old keys, so after regenerating you'll need to update the keys in all agent instances and all other instances, like APIs, Logic Apps and Microsoft Flow"

If someone has any experience with this it would be so helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

If we regenerate the azure log Analytics Workspace key, the old key will expire and all gent instances connecting the workspace with the key will be disconnected.

Comment: first of all, thanks for replying to my question!! Appreciate it. However, do you have any supported documentation for this? I have tested this scenario with one machine and it stayed connected even after the key was regenerated. Is it a matter of time?

Comment: See my answer, it is a matter of time (up to 3 months). More information can be found on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/agent-windows#workspace-id-and-key

Answer (score 0):

The page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/agent-windows#workspace-id-and-key says the following:

> While regenerating the Log Analytics Workspace shared keys is possible, the intention for this is not to immediately restrict access to any agents currently using those keys. Agents use the key to generate a certificate that expires after three months. Regenerating the shared keys will only prevent agents from renewing their certificates, not continuing to use those certificates until they expire.

Changing the key of the monitor agent is done by going to the control panel -> System and Security -> Microsoft Monitoring Agent and select the Azure Log Analytics tab.
Here you can click on 'Edit' on the workspace and change the key. Clicking on 'OK' or 'Apply' in the main window will cause the agent to restart.